# Is it possible to Format text in MS Teams Notification for Activity Feed?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to format text to Bold/Italics in Teams Activity Feed for the Notification. Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, how?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it's possible the markdown that Teams supports in messages could work here as well. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

Comment: For previewText, Microsoft Teams will only show first 150 characters. Possible values for contentType are 'text' and 'html'. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I tried that bold using markdown but it did not work and showed as it is. @Prasad-MSFT, could you please an example with HTML formatting? the link which you shared od not have that in it

Comment: These is no such document available, and markdown doesn't seem to be applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

yeah there is still no such functionality found by ms-teams end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).